# Artifactory in Docker produce errors during start

Tags: artifactory

I'm newbie in Jfrog Artifactory and I having problems with starting the container with Artifactory.

It works, and I see the web-interface, but I'm concerned about the errors in the console.

**Here is the docker-compose:**

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  artifactory:
    image: docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss
    container_name: artifactory
  environment:
    JF_SHARED_NODE_IP: "127.0.0.1"
    JF_SHARED_NODE_ID: "artifactory"
    JF_SHARED_NODE_NAME: "artifactory"
  ports:
    - 8082:8082
    - 8081:8081
  volumes:
    - ./jfrog/artifactory/var/:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory
    - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
  logging:
    driver: json-file
    options:
      max-size: "50m"
      max-file: "10"
  ulimits:
    nproc: 65535
    nofile:
      soft: 32000
      hard: 40000
```

**Before I launch it, I execute the following:**

```
sudo mkdir -p ./jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/
touch ./jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml
chown -R 1030:1030 ./jfrog/artifactory/var
chmod -R 777 ./jfrog/artifactory/var
```

**Here is the startup log:**
[artifactory_startup.log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pdXkoUXghWxE1Hv-HHYjNtu-2NeRIkaM/view?usp=sharing) (sorry for uploading the log on Goggle Drive. It's too large for the stackoverflow post)

**I'm concerned about these strings:**

`[jfac ] [WARN ] [976f1c9489fa2680] [c.z.h.u.DriverDataSource:70   ] [ocalhost-startStop-1] - Registered driver with driverClassName=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.`

`[jfac ] [WARN ] [976f1c9489fa2680] [o.j.c.ExecutionUtils:165      ] [pool-8-thread-2     ] - Retry 10 Elapsed 5.22 secs failed: Registration with router on URL http://localhost:8046 failed with error: UNAVAILABLE: io exception. Trying again`

```
[jfrt ] [ERROR] [                ] [o.j.c.w.FileWatcher:221       ] [Thread-6            ] - Unknown exception while watching for file changes: null
artifactory  | java.lang.NullPointerException: null
artifactory  |  at org.jfrog.config.watch.FileWatcher.lambda$doWatch$2(FileWatcher.java:202)
artifactory  |  at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
artifactory  |  at org.jfrog.config.watch.FileWatcher.doWatch(FileWatcher.java:201)
artifactory  |  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

`[jfrou] [WARN ] [6424ea6f8b2dc101] [local_topology.go:256         ] [main                ] - Readiness test failed with the following error: "required node services are missing or unhealthy"`

Please, help me find out what these errors mean. Or I can just use the service and all is OK?

Comment: Avoid creating the `touch ./jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.yaml`. The container has a default one it will use. You are blanking out all the system configuration. See if it helps (remove the file you created).

Comment: As for the service, you can use it. The errors come during the startup when services are still coming up and aligning. The line 
`###############################################################
###   All services started successfully in 54.067 seconds   ###
###############################################################`
Is a good indication.

Comment: I've found out that it works for some time and then the following errors start appearing:`artifactory  | 2021-11-04T13:03:55.206Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [7e98a9c84b8f8e4c] [o.j.a.c.h.AccessHttpClient:136] [ttp-nio-8081-exec-30] - Error while executing /api/v1/users/ on access. Exception message: Read timed out`.
Then the interface hangs.

Comment: Try following the official Docker compose install in https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Installing+Artifactory#InstallingArtifactory-DockerComposeInstallation. You just need to change the image to `artifactory-oss`.
Do this from scratch.

Comment: Eldad, Thanks for you help.

It's turned out that I needed to give more resources to the Artifactory in Docker. It was 2Gb for all containers and only 4 CPUs. I gave them 8 and 8 and all works now.

Comment: Perfect! I suggest you add the summary of the actions you did as a formal answer for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging I've found out that Tomcat and JVM can't get enough CPU threads. The solution is to give more recourses to the containers. I've completely forgotten to read about system requirements.